# PHP get raw cookie

Tags: php, cookies

Maybe this is a duplicate question but I couldn't find it.

The thing is I have a stored cookie in the browser like `username=test+1@test.com` and when I read it from the php `$_COOKIE["username"]` I get `test 1@test.com`. I want to have the cookie without url decoding, just the way the browser is sending it. I know that there exist the funciton `setrawcookie()` and I want something like the reverse of that (like `getrawcookie`).

Thanks

Comment: Post the code, we need to see what you are really doing.

Comment: there is no getrawcookie, because you can use `$_SERVER['Cookie']`

Comment: @Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez I'm just reading the cookie with `$_COOKIE["username"]` and I'm getting it url decoded like the example I say.

@Marc B As you said `$_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIES"]` works but it shows me all the cookies. Is there a way of getting just the cookie I need like in $_COOKIE["cookie"]? Thanks!

Comment: I mean `$_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"]`

Answer (score 1):

Based on dubafek's comment I built this to get raw cookie values:

```
$raw_cookies = (array_reduce(
    explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] ?? ''),
    function($carry, $item) {
        $pair_arr = explode('=', $item);
        $carry[ trim($pair_arr[0]) ] = trim($pair_arr[1]);
        return $carry;
    },
    []
) ?: []);
```

From there you can use `$raw_cookies` as you would `$_COOKIE`. I needed to have the raw values when forwarding cookies in a curl call.

Edit: There are minor differences between the keys of `$raw_cookies` and `$_COOKIE`. For instance, a cookie with key `connect.sid` will appear in `$_COOKIE['connect_sid']` and `$raw_cookies['connect.sid']`. I am not sure what transformations PHP is doing to cookie keys so those may or may not need to be accounted for in your particular implementation.

Comment: I had the same cookie set with and without preceding dot on the domain with different values (I changed how the cookie was set in my application).  This causes it to appear twice in the cookie request header. The $raw_cookies array from the above function happened to keep the first value sent by the browser for the specific key, while $_COOKIE keeps the last value for the same the key.